# Gyroscope signal when mounted on a deflated tire

Tags: kinematics, wheeled-robot, imu, gyroscope, wheel

Before I do the experiment, I am a bit confused about the expected signals provided by a 3-axis gyroscope (angular velocities vs. time) mounted on the edge of a (slightly) deflated car tire when the car is moving.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* afous afous, can you add some detail you your question?  We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: thanks @jsotola and Ben. what if you suppose that I am not a good drawer and the gyroscope is carefully mounted inside the tire (let's say the inner tube) ?

Comment: Deflated because I am focusing on real conditions (the contact with the ground is not concentrated on a single point). Yes, I can mount the sensor on a moving tire without problem (endless solutions to imagine how can a sensor be mounted to observe the mvt of a point). The bicycle upside down is not a good idea since the tire will not be distorted by "rotation" AND "translation"